# Does $\displaystyle\sum_{n\geq 0} \dfrac{n!k^n}{(n+1)^n}$ converge or diverge for $k=\dfrac{19}{7}$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

Does $\displaystyle\sum_{n\geq 0} \dfrac{n!k^n}{(n+1)^n}$ converge or diverge for $k=\dfrac{19}{7}$?

I'm not sure what convergence test I should use for this one. $k=\dfrac{19}{7}$ also seems randomly chosen, so as long as it lies within a certain range, the sum will converge, I think.

Comment: Ratio test${}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should learn more about convergence tests and when to use them. For this problem, you can apply the ratio test.

Let $a_n = \dfrac{n!k^n}{(n+1)^n}.$ So we have that $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \left|\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}\right|=\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\dfrac{\frac{(n+1)!k^{n+1}}{(n+2)^{n+1}}}{\frac{n!k^n}{(n+1)^n}}\\
=\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\dfrac{(n+1)!}{n!}\cdot\dfrac{k^{n+1}}{k^n}\cdot\dfrac{(n+1)^n}{(n+2)^n}\cdot\dfrac{1}{n+2}\\
=\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\dfrac{n+1}{n+2}\cdot k\cdot\left(1-\dfrac{1}{n+2}\right)^n\\
=\dfrac{k}{e}$

by the definition of $e.$ Since $k<e, \dfrac{k}{e}<1$ so by the ratio test the series converges.

Answer (score 1):

By ratio test we obtain

$$\left|\dfrac{(n+1)!k^{n+1}}{(n+2)^{n+1}}\dfrac{(n+1)^n}{n!k^n}\right|=k\frac{n+1}{n+2}\left(1-\frac1{n+2}\right)^n\to \frac ke$$

indeed recall that

$$\left(1-\frac1{n+2}\right)^n=\left[\left(1-\frac1{n+2}\right)^{n+2}\right]^{\frac n {n+2}} \to \frac1e$$

and finally observe that $\frac{19}{7e}<1$.

Answer (score 0):

Apply the ratio test $$ \left|\dfrac{(n+1)!k^{n+1}}{(n+2)^{n+1}}\dfrac{(n+1)^n}{n!k^n}\right|=$$

$$k\frac{n+1}{n+2}\left(1-\frac1{n+2}\right)^n\to \frac ke =0.9985...<1$$

Thus the series converges.